# Can't get klout score to show using ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, jsonp, klout

I am trying to display a klout score on a web page

this is my code

```
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var settings = {

    "url": "http://api.klout.com/v2/user.json/********/score?key=7fn6tcf3zvptq9sw47aknmjr&callback=?",
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $(data, function( inf ) {
       $("#score").append('<li>' + inf.score + '</li>');
     });

  });
</script>

<h2>Klout Score</h2>
<ul id="score"></ul>
```

the json data that im calling  is as follows

```
{"score":10.0,"scoreDelta":{"dayChange":0.0,"weekChange":0.0,"monthChange":0.0},"bucket":"10-19","unscored":true}
```

i cant get the klout score to show What am i doing wrong ??

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove that line of code after `console.log`, as it is not executed and the `append` do not work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var settings = {

    "url": "http://api.klout.com/v2/user.json/233905743529873888/score?key=7fn6tcf3zvptq9sw47aknmjr&callback=?",
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data){  //response is not null or undefined
        $("#score").append('<li>' + data.score + '</li>');
    }else{
       alert('Empty response');
     }


  });
</script>

<h2>Klout Score</h2>
<ul id="score"></ul>
```

It is safe approach to wrap your `append` into `if-else` block as it will be easy and relevant in determining response type (is null or not)

Comment: Thankyou this worked for me and i understand where you got it from thanks so much for your help

Comment: Could you please add a upvote and mark is as accepted so that others can know it is really working.

Comment: i upvoted both of the answers and chose the one that worked best for me , iv only just joined stackoverflow so it didnt register the vote publically sorry

Comment: No problem thanks. If you have any issues related to jquery, javascript or AngularJS you can mail me at ank9803@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Don’t know why you don’t just use the `data` that you get back. Try this instead.

```js
var settings = {

    "url": "http://api.klout.com/v2/user.json/233905743529873888/score?key=7fn6tcf3zvptq9sw47aknmjr&callback=?",
    "method": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "headers": {}
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $("#score").append(
      $('<li/>').text(parseInt(data.score, 10))
    );

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="score"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you for the response i upvoted , the code worked , but i used the one above as im new to ajax and json  and undderstand that response better as iits closer to the code in my question.  Thankyou for your help i will study your answer and learn from it